# how do I write "about four or five hundred US Dollars"

Tags: orthography, numbers

I proofread/edit transcribed witness evidence, and often witnesses will say something like "around four or five thousand dollars".  If the evidence is all about figures, I would sometimes write this in figures as "around $4,000 or $5,000", but it's not strictly what the witness said.  Could I write "around $4- or $5,000"?  Is there a rule I can apply?
Denise

Comment: Wouldn't a rule for this be laid down by the entity you work for? I would assume there must be some kind of official protocol you are required (or expected) to comply with.

Comment: Incidentally, the title of your question refers to "about four or five hundred pounds", but the body of your question concerns "around four or five thousand dollars". (Bad exchange rate?  :)

Comment: You may find this article of use. http://www.grammarbook.com/numbers/numbers.asp

Comment: @ErikKowal That's an awesome exchange rate if you started with the pounds!

Comment: You absolutely need to be asking this question to the people you work for, not to random strangers on the internet. We are not lawyers and we do not know what rules you operate under.

Comment: In complete agreement with David.  This question is I'm afraid somewhat bizarre - almost disturbing!  (ie, how could a legal system be in place where transcription professionals do not have the relevant policy completely integrated to their work??)

Comment: I like to summarize my employer's rulebook as “we transcribe verbatim except when we don't.”  I prefer `four or five thousand dollars` but my employer insists on `$4,000 or $5,000`— but this isn't legal material.

Answer (score 7):

I'd circumvent the whole issue, *and*, while at it, satisfy a certain subset of the puritanical prescriptivist party by writing it as:
"**around four or five thousand dollars**", just as you did in the question itself.

It's unambiguous, accurate, and a literal transcription of what was said.

Comment: Many thanks for all the comments.  The purist in me wants to write it out in full "around four or five thousand dollars" to keep it verbatim.  But if the witness is doing a walk-through of a vast spread-sheet and repeated uses similar terms, I may revert to the figures version "around $4,000 or $5,000" to keep it readable.   Centaurus, your comment on clarity is key, so may thanks.

Comment: Peter Shor, you are dead right about transcripts in that they must be verbatim (witnesses, that is. I can tidy counsel).  I punctuate for sense (and make decisions about how I understood what was meant).  If something is ambiguous I must leave it as such.  Lawyers have the opportunity to discuss what witnesses meant by what they said (and will do so ad infinitum).

Comment: You can always write it in full and add the figures in parenthesis. With decent typography, it should be easy enough to read the transcript or scan for the figures.